# seeing duplicated data from load action on 09/27/2012

Tags: google-bigquery

we just noticed around 09/27/2012 our data have been duplicated from doing csv files upload (using Java API). Logs indicated no error during upload but we have confirmed a majority of rows during that day have been duplicated (there is distinct timestamp in micro second per row) Is there any known glitches during that day? We're at a loss of how to prevent this from happening again.

Thanks for any feed back.

Comment: Hi Hung Huynh, did my suggestion below help?

Comment: I'm gathering the logs and checking the jobs' status and will post back. Our .csv.gz files are named with unique timestamps and the job ids are created from these filenames so if a file is uploaded twice it'll fail due to conflicting job ids.

Comment: In 2014, I'm occasionally seeing something like this as well in recent uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking into this for us. It is hard (almost impossible) to believe that data got duplicated on the bigquery side. That said nothing we can see seems to indicate otherwise. As mentioned we have a microsecond timestamp value on every row. For the two job IDs referenced I picked a row at random and made sure that within all of the data we've ever imported it was a unique value. When I run the same query I get two (identical) rows in our bigquery table.

Comment: FYI the bug has been found and fixed. The issue was coalescing the table, rather than the import. We tried coalescing the same table twice, and both succeeded, causing many of the rows to be duplicated. Your table still has the extra rows. If you would like, I can remove the rows from the duplicated coalesce operation (this can be reversed if it causes problems).

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I'm pretty sure we'd like to go ahead and get the duplicate data removed. But I have a few questions first...

Comment: When was (or has even?) the bug fix been applied in production?

Comment: What details would you need to know in order to remove the duped rows? It would be quite a task on this end to determine precisely all the job IDs for which we can detect duplicated data

Comment: I've got all of the information I need to remove the duplicate rows ... they all have the same storage id. I can just mark that id as garbage (if it causes problems,the operation can be undone for 7 days).

Comment: We developed a workaround in the face of this bug. Instead of importing to our main table, we are now importing each new batch of data to a brand new temporary table. After the import is done we run a count query to make sure we observe no duplicates (we might also spot check some N number of rows). if it looks okay then and only then do we copy to our main table. My question is whether this workaround would have actually detected the bug? It certainly makes our import process more complicated but it seems like we shouldn't rely completely on a perfect backend over there.

Comment: The problem wasn't the import -- the import only added the data once. The problem surfaced when we coalesced multiple imports into a single backend record. We did this twice from two different servers. The underlying bug has been fixed that allowed this to happen (but not yet pushed to production). In the mean time, we turned off all of the coalescers except 1, so the issue should not occur.

Comment: Just a quick question: Are you certain that it is only those two imports that had duplicated data? It appeared that many more imports may have been duplicated at the same time.

Comment: also... this may be easier to continue over e-mail. Feel free to e-mail me -- my last name at google.com.

Comment: @JordanTigani helped a lot also in our case - we had similar problem with some data duplication. More about it is described here: http://www.dzone.com/links/r/lies_damned_lies_and_statistics_2.html

Answer (score 1):

First: make sure (by checking the load job history), that you didn't actually end up running a load job twice. If you are using the [bq command line client](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool):

```
# Show all jobs for your selected project
bq ls -j

# Will result in a list such as:
...
job_d8fc9d7eefb2e9243b1ffde484b3ab8a   load      FAILURE   29 Sep 00:35:26   0:00:00   
job_4704a91875d9e0c64f7aaa8de0458696   load      SUCCESS   29 Sep 00:28:45   0:00:05   
...

# Find the load jobs pertaining to the time of data loading. To show detailed information
# about which files you ingested in the load job, run a command on the individual jobs
# that might have been repeats:
bq --format prettyjson show -j job_d8fc9d7eefb2e9243b1ffde484b3ab8a
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know of any reason why data would be duplicated during import. If you provide us with more information, such as your job id and project id that would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

In general, as Michael mentioned in his answer, people who see duplicated data have generally run the same job twice. (note that if a job fails, the table should not be modified in any way).

A way to prevent these kinds of collisions is to name your job, since we enforce job name uniqueness on a per-project level. For example, if you do a load once a day, you might want to name your job id something like "job_2012_10_08_load1". That way if you tried to run the same job twice, the second one would fail on start.

Comment: We do have a scheme similar as you proposed. Our scheme is using the filenames as part of the jobId and the filename itself has a unique timestamp generated every 5 minutes. The 2 job ids we confirmed that were producing duplicated rows are: **apps_prod_orgsite_terracotta_lan_bigquery-data-2012-09-27_23-22-51-729_csv_gz**
   and   **apps_prod_orgsite_terracotta_lan_bigquery-data-2012-09-27_01-47-43-901_csv_gz**